# How to Generate Payment Hash in android payubiz Integration?

Tags: android, payment-gateway

I am integrating `payubiz` payment gateway. I finished most of the steps in payment integration.

Getting error

> Required payment hash

How to generate this in android?

Comment: Made it understandable

Answer (score 0):

check whether you had set param for hash. 
e.g. mPaymentParams.setHash("your payment hash");